# Perl: Greedy nature refuses to work

Tags: perl

I am trying to replace a string with another string, but the greedy nature doesn't seem to be working for me. Below is my code where "PERFORM GET-APLCY" is identified and replaced properly, but string "PERFORM GET-APLCY-SOI-CVG-WVR" and many other such strings are being replaced by the the replacement string for "PERFORM GET-APLCY".

```
s/PERFORM $func[$i]\.*/#  PERFORM $func[$i]\.\n $hash{$func[$i]}/g;
```

where the full stop is optional during string match and replacement. I have also tried giving the pattern to be matched as $func[$i]\b
Please help me understand what the issue could be.

Thanks in advance,
Faez

Comment: You do realize, that .* is greedy and .? is not?

Comment: Oh yes yes... I was trying it with ? and by mistake pasted this code. Please check it now.

Comment: What is the value of $func[$i] ? The part of your regexp \.? will match 0 or 1 full-stop, and will prefer 1 time, to 0 times. Is this what you want? Ahhh - you've edited it now. See BSen's comment below.

Comment: Then you've escaped dot sign. So, you're matching from 0 to inf dots after $func[$i] value

Comment: Yeah, inf does doesn't matter. Main issue is that PATTERN ain't acting greedy enough to match extended version of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `GET-APLCY-` should not match `GET-APLCY.`, if the dot is optional?

Easy solution: sort your array by length in descending order.

```
@func = sort { length $b <=> length $a } @func
```

Testing script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my %hash = ('GET-APLCY'              => 'REP1',
            'GET-APLCY-SOI-CVG-WVR'  => 'REP2',
            'GET-APLCY-SOI-MNG-CVRW' => 'REP3',
           );

my @func = sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %hash;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print;
    print "\t -> \t";
    for my $i (0 .. $#func) {
        s/$func[$i]/$hash{$func[$i]}/;
    }
    say;
}

__DATA__
GET-APLCY param
GET-APLCY- param
GET-APLCY. param
GET-APLCY-SOI. param
GET-APLCY-SOI-CVG-WVR param
GET-APLCY-SOI-MNG-CVRW param
```

Comment: Whatever comes after PERFORM are function names. Hence GET-APLCY, GET-APLCY-SOI-CVG-WVR, GET-APLCY-SOI-RI-ELIG etc needs to be replaced accordingly to their values in respective hashes. A full stop at the end of the PATTERN is optional.

Comment: Yes, Indeed! It will definitely try to match GET-APLCY with the optional dot :)  So I tried the following: s/PERFORM $func[$i]-?.*/#  PERFORM $func[$i]\.\n $hash{$func[$i]}/;
Doesn't work...

Comment: You want the pattern NOT followed by a -, I guess. But sorting the patterns should work, too.

Comment: I want both. GET-APLCY is replaced by REP1 , GET-APLCY-SOI-CVG-WVR is replaced REP2, GET-APLCY-SOI-MNG-CVRW is replaced by REP3 and so on..
I tried ur sorting technique.. same results :(

Comment: reverse sort worked in my case
    my @func = reverse sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %hash;
But am still perplexed how ur sorting technique resolved the issue. Could u please explain, if u don't mind?

Comment: @faezshingeri: If you first replace the longee strings, their substrings then cannot match them. How the reversed sort can help I cannot tell.

Comment: The program still fails to identify a few PERFORM (followed by func names) and correspondingly replace them.

Comment: The problem is.. The "PERFORM func-name" statement which is replaced by "# PERFORM func-name. (followed by the REPLACEMENT value) of the corresponding key" itself contains a couple of independent PERFORM func-name statements.. I mean to say The content in $hash{$1} has a few lines which has its own "PERFORM func-name" statements. And these are the culprit PERFORM statements not being replaced! I hope I didn't confuse u much.

Comment: and Yes, I want these PERFORM statements to be replaced too.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be looping over function names, and calling `s///` for each one. An alternative is to use the `e` option, and do them all in one go (without a loop):

```
my %hash = (
  'GET-APLCY'             => 'replacement 1',
  'GET-APLCY-SOI-CVG-WVR' => 'replacement 2',
);

s{ 
  PERFORM \s+   # 'PERFORM' keyword 
  ([A-Z-]+)     # the original function name
  \.?           # an optional period
}{
  "#  PERFORM $1.\n" . $hash{$1};
}xmsge;
```

The `e` causes the replacement part to be evaluated as an expression. Basically, the first part finds all `PERFORM` calls (I'm assuming that the function names are all upper case with '-' between them – adjust otherwise). The second part replaces that line with the text you want to appear.

I've also used the `x`, `m`, and `s` options, which is what allows the comments in the regular expression, among other things. You can find more about these under `perldoc perlop`.

A plain version of the `s`-line should be:

```
s/PERFORM ([A-Z-]+)\.?/"#  PERFORM $1.\n" . $hash{$1}/eg;
```

Comment: This was indeed a brilliant way to do. Also, I do have the function names in uppercase and digits mixed. Hence I used \w.
But it fails to identify alot of PERFORM (followed by func names) in the file. I am trying my best to debug it but still no luck.

Comment: Ok now I found what the problem is. The "PERFORM func-name" statement which is replaced by "# PERFORM func-name. (followed by the REPLACEMENT value) of the corresponding key" itself contains a couple of independent PERFORM func-name statements.. I mean to say The content in $hash{$1} has a few lines which has its own "PERFORM func-name" statements. And these are the culprit PERFORM statements not being replaced! I hope I didn't confuseu much.
Now what I am trying to do now is find the size of hash value and then using seek operation, will take the filepointer back.
Vl b happy to knw ur inputs

Answer (score 0):

I guess that $func[$i] contains "GET-APLCY". If so, this is because the star only applies to the dot, an actual dot, not "any character". Try

```
s/PERFORM $func[$i].*/#  PERFORM $func[$i]\.\n $hash{$func[$i]}/g;
```

Comment: I had tried this earlier. Tried it again now. *sigh*  Doesn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you trying to do some kind of loop for $i. And in that case most likely 
GET-APLCY is located in @func array before GET-APLCY-SOI-CVG-WVR. So I recommend to reverse sort @func before entering loop.